# Dynamically adding node to node-set based on condition

Tags: xslt

This is my input xml file

```
<Collection>
<Teach>
<DeptNo>5613</DeptNo>
<DeptName>Computers</DeptName>
<SubjectNo>234</SubjectNo>
<SubjectName>XML</SubjectName>
<Teacher>Sai</Teacher>
</Teach>
<Teach>
<DeptNo>5617</DeptNo>
<DeptName>Electronics</DeptName>
<SubjectNo>789</SubjectNo>
<SubjectName>Circuits</SubjectName>
<Teacher>Hari</Teacher>
</Teach>
<Teach>
<DeptNo>5613</DeptNo>
<DeptName>Computers</DeptName>
<SubjectNo>239</SubjectNo>
<SubjectName>XSLT</SubjectName>
<Teacher>Suri</Teacher>
</Teach>
<Teach>
<DeptNo>5689</DeptNo>
<DeptName>Maths</DeptName>
<SubjectNo>749</SubjectNo>
<SubjectName>Trigonometry</SubjectName>
<Teacher>Arya</Teacher>
</Teach>
<Teach>
<DeptNo>5617</DeptNo>
<DeptName>Electronics</DeptName>
<SubjectNo>789</SubjectNo>
<SubjectName>Circuits</SubjectName>
<Teacher>Bharat</Teacher>
</Teach>
</Collection>
```

Now I want the follwing output xml file based on DeptNo if it is same then check Subjectno and if it is same then add teacher to subject. Also do the same for Subject and Dept. My output file would be

```
<Collection>
<DeptList>
<DeptNo>5613</DeptNo>
<DeptName>Computers</DeptName>
<SubjectList>
<SubjectNo>234</SubjectNo>
<SubjectName>XML</SubjectName>
<TeacherList>
<Teacher>Sai</Teacher>
</TeacherList>
</SubjectList>
<SubjectList>
<SubjectNo>239</SubjectNo>
<SubjectName>XSLT</SubjectName>
<TeacherList>
<Teacher>Suri</Teacher>
</TeacherList>
</SubjectList>
</DeptList>
<DeptList>
<DeptNo>5617</DeptNo>
<DeptName>Electronics</DeptName>
<SubjectList>
<SubjectNo>789</SubjectNo>
<SubjectName>Circuits</SubjectName>
<TeacherList>
<Teacher>Hari</Teacher>
<Teacher>Bharat</Teacher>
</TeacherList>
</SubjectList> 
</DeptList>
<DeptList>
<DeptNo>5689</DeptNo>
<DeptName>Maths</DeptName>
<SubjectList>
<SubjectNo>749</SubjectNo>
<SubjectName>Trigonometry</SubjectName>
<TeacherList>
<Teacher>Arya</Teacher>
</TeacherList>
</SubjectList>
</DeptList>
</Collection>
```

Comment: It is a grouping problem. Do you want to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime to solve that? Or an XSLT 1.0 processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet to be run with Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime or any other XSLT 2.0 processor:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Collection">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Teach" group-by="DeptNo">
      <DeptList>
        <xsl:copy-of select="DeptNo, DeptName"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="SubjectNo">
          <SubjectList>
            <xsl:copy-of select="SubjectNo, SubjectName"/>
            <TeacherList>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/Teacher"/>
            </TeacherList>
          </SubjectList>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </DeptList>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[edit]
In case you need an XSLT 1.0 solution you can use [Muechian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="deptNo" match="Teach" use="DeptNo"/>
<xsl:key name="deptAndSubject" match="Teach" use="concat(DeptNo, '|', SubjectNo)"/>

<xsl:template match="Collection">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- <xsl:for-each-group select="Teach" group-by="DeptNo"> -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Teach[generate-id() = generate-id(key('deptNo', DeptNo)[1])]">
      <DeptList>
        <xsl:copy-of select="DeptNo | DeptName"/>
        <!--  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="SubjectNo"> -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('deptNo', DeptNo)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('deptAndSubject', concat(DeptNo, '|', SubjectNo))[1])]">
          <SubjectList>
            <xsl:copy-of select="SubjectNo | SubjectName"/>
            <TeacherList>
              <xsl:copy-of select="key('deptAndSubject', concat(DeptNo, '|', SubjectNo))/Teacher"/>
            </TeacherList>
          </SubjectList>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </DeptList>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I intentionally commented out the XSLT 2.0 `for-each-group` instructions to show the equivalent XSLT 1.0 key based Muenchian grouping constructs.

Comment: Thanks I got it. Happy if you give answer without for-each-group i.e, based on equal condition.

Comment: Well it is a grouping problem so I will solve that with existing approaches to group. In case you want an XSLT 1.0 solution I will edit and post one using keys and Muenchian grouping.